# What's the name of this blue tomato cultivar?

Tags: identification, tomatoes, cultivar

This variety is called "Tomate Azul" (Spanish) and "Tomàquet Blau" (Catalan) at the Alcampo hypermarket. There are many varieties of blue tomatoes so I wonder what's the English name for this particular cultivar

I've found [an article in Spanish](http://www.tuinen.es/seleccion-de-plantas/tomates-azules-los-tomates-terapeuticos) about the blue tomatoes, the photos in the article match my photos.

[These are the photos taken by me](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Azul_(tomato)), this particular tomato had 345 grams and it wasn't the biggest in the batch.

[image: enter link description here]

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: What color is the flesh?

Comment: When it comes to tomato names, the practice that I see tomato gurus (e.g. Dr. Carolyn Male) use is to keep the original name, despite it being from a foreign language. Translated names might sometimes be used, but it's not considered a good practice. Sometimes they have alternate names in different countries, but that's more the exception than the rule (e.g. Grosse Lisse and Trophy are supposed to be the same). So, if the name was originally Tomate Azul, you'd probably still call it that in the USA (or maybe just Azul, if tomate wasn't part of the actual name).

Comment: It could just be a generic name for selling it. People don't always use the real variety names. This might be the same as if you found a seed packet that said, "Red Tomato". That doesn't necessarily mean the variety is called Red (although it may be).

Answer (score 2):

The name of the cultivar is ***'Indigo Rose'***.

The origin of the cultivar is Peru. It has therapheutic value to people, beside nutrutional.

From an article about Tomate Azul:

(http://www.elhuertodelabuelo.es/es/tomates/36-tomate-azul.html)

> Este es el tomate original , lanzado en 2012 por el Dr. Jim Myers de la universidad estatal de Oregón. Utilizando métodos convencionales de mejora mediante cruces con tomates silvestres de Perú y de las Islas Galápagos, para obtener su color púrpura profundo rico en Antiocianina. La Antiocianina es un poderoso antioxidante que nos protege de muchas enfermedades y del envejecimiento prematuro. El Tomate Azul, desarrolla el color morado oscuro en aquellas zonas de la piel que reciben directamente la luz solar, pero es necesario que madure completamente para percibir todo su sabor. No está maduro hasta que el fruto se ablanda, el fondo cambia de verde a rojo, y en el interior el color de la carne es rojo oscuro. Producción media de frutos redondos de 60-75 grs. De peso. Planta de porte indeterminado. Recolección a partir de 75 dias.

Translation: (feel free to correct it)

> This is the original tomato, launched in 2012 by Dr. Jim Myers of Oregon State University. Using conventional methods of improvement through crosses with wild tomatoes from Peru and the Galapagos Islands, to obtain its deep purple color rich in anthocyanin. Anthocyanin is a powerful antioxidant that protects us from many diseases and premature aging. Tomate Azul develops the dark purple color in those areas of the skin that directly receive sunlight, but it is necessary that it ripens completely to reach its full flavor. It is not ripe until the fruit softens, the background changes from green to red, and inside the color of the flesh is dark red. Average production of round fruits of 60-75 grams. Of weight. Plant of indeterminate size. Collection from 75 days.

From the biography of Dr. Jim Myers:

> I have developed and released 13 dry bean, one green bean, and four tomato cultivars. One tomato cultivar (co-released with Dr. J.R. Baggett) is ‘Legend’, an early, large fruited, parthenocarpic, determinate slicer with late blight resistance. My graduate students and I were the first to create high anthocyanin tomatoes using conventional breeding approaches. The first release of this kind – ‘Indigo Rose’ has been available in the U.S. since 2012 and is now moving into global markets. ‘Indigo Cherry Drops’ and Indigo Pear Drops” are two new Indigo cultivars that have been released and more are in the pipeline.

Comment: There are lots of blue (anthocyanin skinned) tomatoes, although Indigo Rose was among the first. Indigo Rose is a small tomato (bred by OSU), and it's round with a smooth shape. This one appears to be quite large (even though we don't have anything to compare its size to), and a beefsteak. The closest breed I know about is Black Beauty, but I'm afraid it doesn't match, either. I'm guessing it's a newer breed from the local area, or otherwise outside the USA.  I've seen unusual foreign blue tomatoes before. Indigo Cherry Drops is a cherry. Indigo Pear drops is a pear tomato (and pretty small).

Comment: I've seen pictures of unusual large foreign blue tomatoes before, I mean. I've never heard what kind they really are, but they don't match any of the known varieties (especially among the popular ones) in the USA that I've found. Most of those are cherries or small. Black Beauty, Red Beauty, Indigo Apple, and Blue Beauty are among the largest.

Comment: This one had 345 grams and it was about 12 cm on it's longest side - quite large